# 3D texture size affecting program output without error being thrown

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, graphics, textures

First, I am using the `glDebugMessage()` instead of `glGetError()` to determine errors.

Second, I am allocating a 3D texture storage as follows:

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, 512, 512, 303, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

When the depth coponent is 303 or less, my program works exactly as expected (I allocate a color in the texture and I see that color as output), when that parameter is 304 or higher, the program doesn't work (the screen is black).

I have tested the same program in different machines, and depending on the computer the treshhold changes, sometimes it's higher, sometimes lower.

My hypothesis is then that some drivers cannot allocate enough memory to handle this texture. But no error is being thrown, or at least, the debug message is not getting called.

Is there a way I can verify that I am indeed requesting more memory than can be allocated and extend said memory somehow?

Comment: Maybe you could try to query the available memory through something like `GL_GPU_MEM_INFO_CURRENT_AVAILABLE_MEM_NVX` (assuming you're using an Nvidia gpu) and compare with what you're requesting. https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NVX/NVX_gpu_memory_info.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep the 303 texture is ~1.2GByte if I compute it correctly. Your gfx card however also need memory for framebuffer and other stuff too. Sadly there is no common GL API to query available memory. There are extensions for this however. This is how I query basic info in my **OpenGL** engine (**VCL/C++**):

```cpp
AnsiString OpenGLscreen::glinfo()
    {
    AnsiString txt="";
    txt+=glGetAnsiString(GL_VENDOR)+"\r\n";
    txt+=glGetAnsiString(GL_RENDERER)+"\r\n";
    txt+="OpenGL ver: "+glGetAnsiString(GL_VERSION)+"\r\n";
    if (ext_is_supported("GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info"))
        {
        GLint x,y,z;
        x=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_GPU_MEMORY_INFO_CURRENT_AVAILABLE_VIDMEM_NVX,&x);
        y=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_GPU_MEMORY_INFO_DEDICATED_VIDMEM_NVX,&y);
        z=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_GPU_MEMORY_INFO_TOTAL_AVAILABLE_MEMORY_NVX,&z);
        txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("GPU memory: %i/%i/%i MByte\r\n",x>>10,y>>10,z>>10); // GPU free/GPU total/GPU+CPU shared total
        x=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_GPU_MEMORY_INFO_EVICTION_COUNT_NVX,&x);
        y=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_GPU_MEMORY_INFO_EVICTED_MEMORY_NVX,&y);
        txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("GPU blocks: %i used: %i MByte\r\n",x,y>>10);
        }
    if (ext_is_supported("GL_ATI_meminfo"))
        {
        GLint x0,x1,x2,x3; // free,largest available block,free auxiliary, largest available auxiliary
        x0=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_VBO_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,&x0);
        x1=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_VBO_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,&x1);
        x2=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_VBO_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,&x2);
        x3=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_VBO_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,&x3);
        txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("VBO memory: %i MByte\r\n",x0>>10);
        x0=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,&x0);
        x1=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,&x1);
        x2=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,&x2);
        x3=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,&x3);
        txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("TXR memory: %i MByte\r\n",x0>>10);
        x0=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_RENDERBUFFER_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,&x0);
        x1=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_RENDERBUFFER_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,&x1);
        x2=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_RENDERBUFFER_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,&x2);
        x3=0; glGetIntegerv(GL_RENDERBUFFER_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,&x3);
        txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("BUF memory: %i MByte\r\n",x0>>10);
        }
    return txt;
    }
```

So extract the **nVidia** and **ATI/AMD** memory queries. and port to your environment.

btw I just realized in order the above code to work you need also this:

```cpp
AnsiString glGetAnsiString(GLuint id)
    {
    GLubyte a,*p=(GLubyte*)(void*)glGetString(id);
    AnsiString s;
    for(s="";p;p++)
        {
        a=p[0];
        if (!a) break;
        s+=char(a);
        }
    return s;
    }
```

Which just converts result of `glGetString` from `char*` to VCL's `AnsiString` which I use heavily. So in different environment than VCL just stick to `char*` or convert to string type you got...

Comment: There is no difference in the ouptut in between having 512 and 1024 as the texture's width, height, depth.

WIth 512, it works on my current computer, with 1024, it's porbably too large. But querying the system with your method displays 7729 mb out of 8192 in both cases.

Comment: @Makogan it depends on HW and SW GL implementation how the texture is handled internally and **how big block of memory** it needs. I do not see inside GPU memory management however so I can not help further other than that not whole memory is suited for textures ...  For example Win32 memory manager has problems with single chunk above 1.2GB  even if there is enough free memory so I suspect on GPU you might hitting similar limitations