# How do I read an openGL constant of my system

Tags: opengl, glx

An open GL error I get seems to be linked to the `MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS_ARB`. (as suggested in the answer [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-93883)

What determines this constant (graphic hardware, graphic driver, openGL version ?), and how can I check its value under Linux (nvidia hardware)?

Answer (score 0):

This limit is related to used gfx HW and its driver. In OpenGL you can obtain such values on CPU side using this:

```
GLint x;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS_ARB,&x);
```

On my setup:

```
Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL 4.5.0 NVIDIA 368.22
Render: GeForce GTX 550 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
```

it returns:

```
max vertex uniform components: 4096
```

In order to use this you need working OpenGL 1.0 context or better and know the numeric value of the queried stuff. That is usually stored in `gl.h` or `glext.h` in your case its the latter and in case you do not want to include `glext.h` just add this to your code (C++) before use:

```
#define GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS_ARB 0x8B4A
```

Comment: Is this C++ code? Can you provide the full program and includes needed?

Comment: @sayanel You need OpenGL context. I do not have any Linux example as I have only windows ones [this one is simplest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19099162/2521214). However the only thing you need is OpenGL 1.0 context and the queried constant id from `glext.h` so either include it or just use `#define GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS_ARB 0x8B4A` instead. If you do not know how to create GL context use some lib like GLUT or google a OpenGL tutorial for linux. Yes the code is in C++ however as you can see the `GLint` is OpenGL type and there is no code just single OpenGL function call.

Comment: @sayanel here is my [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) with all the GL extentions (using GLEW) and includes. The difference between Windows and Linux will be in the function starting with `wgl...` prefix Most likely they will be called the same with the same parameters just with different prefix I bet `glX...`

Comment: @sayanel Also if you want more info from the gfx and OpenGL see [3D texture size affecting program output without error being thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385807/2521214) as some stuff is obtained with different GL functions