# How print out the OpenGl version of a GPU and put it in a string in Opengl and C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, stdstring

I need to print out the OpenGL Version of my GPU in an application and then put it in a string.

Comment: I also recommend a library called IMGUI which allows you to create a gui in opengl which makes it easier to log things. https://github.com/ocornut/imgui.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35826975/2521214 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385807/2521214

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code as an example:

```
std::cout << "" << std::endl;
std::cout << "" << "OpenGL Vendor: " << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << std::endl;
std::cout << "" << "OpenGL Renderer: " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;
std::cout << "" << "OpenGL Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
std::cout << "" << "OpenGL Shading Language Version: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;
std::cout << "" << std::endl;

std::string Vendor(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glGetString(GL_VENDOR)));
std::string Renderer(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glGetString(GL_RENDERER)));
std::string Version(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glGetString(GL_VERSION)));
std::string ShadingLanguageVersion(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)));

mystring = "\n";
mystring = "OpenGL Vendor: " + Vendor + "\n";
mystring = "OpenGL Renderer : " + Renderer + "\n";
mystring = "OpenGL Version: " + Version + "\n";
mystring = "OpenGL Shading Language Version: " + ShadingLanguageVersion + "\n";
mystring = "\n";
```

I also recommend [this](https://docs.gl/) documentation.

Comment: Definitely want to mention that you'll need a current GL context for any of that to work.