# Can't get available GPU memory

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, gpu

I try to get gpu available memory with code

```
bool bMemInfo1 = GLEW_NVX_gpu_memory_info; // false
bool bMemInfo2 = glewIsSupported("GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info"); // false
bool bMemInfo3 = glewGetExtension("GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info"); // false

GLint info = 0;

glGetIntegerv(GPU_MEMORY_INFO_CURRENT_AVAILABLE_VIDMEM_NVX, @info);

GLenum err = glGetError(); // 1280
if (GLEW_OK != err)
{
    cout << glewGetErrorString(err) << endl; // Unknown error
}
```

And I can't do it in my case. Could you explain why, please? Is there a possibility to obtain available GPU memory?

Comment: Well, NVX stands for NVidia extension, so if your GPU is not nvidia, it's likely it's just not available.

Comment: What is `@info` supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks. But What should I do in case of common GPU? Is there a chance to get need info?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [3D texture size affecting program output without error being thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375686/3d-texture-size-affecting-program-output-without-error-being-thrown)

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL was invented long before 3D GPUs. These things you’re trying to use are GL extensions, not part of any OpenGL standard. They may or may not work depending on OS version and GPU model.

If you’re on Windows, see [DedicatedVideoMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/ns-dxgi-dxgi_adapter_desc) field returned by [IDXGIAdapter::GetDesc()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiadapter-getdesc) method.

If you’re on OSX, there’s `kIOFBMemorySizeKey` value you [can query](https://github.com/tmkk/scratch/blob/master/vram.c#L49-L57).

On Linux you’re out of luck, the OS doesn’t expose a consistent API to query that information. There’re device-specific ways which depend on GPU model, and vary widely: `lspci` tool won't work on many embedded SOCs, `nvidia-smi` tool only works for nVidia, `vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties()` function requires Vulkan-capable GPU and drivers…